# Using linux's EHSET

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, usb

I'm trying to certify USB on our device that is running Linux 4.14. For windows systems we were using https://www.usb.org/usb2tools. For linux the only option I have found is a kernel module called EHSET. Unfortunately I can't manage to get it working, can You please help?

I have added the following configuration:

- CONFIG_USB_HCD_TEST_MODE=y
- USB_EHSET_TEST_FIXTURE=m

Then on the system I type in `modprobe ehset`. After this looking at the [source code of ehset.c](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/usb/misc/ehset.c?h=v4.14) I assumed that inserting USB stick with VendorID:
0x1a0a and ProductID: 0x0108 would start the single step procedure, but it doesn't do anything. The device is loaded as a regular USB stick.

I have not seen any documentation on this topic. Is the kernel driver the only way of testing it in linux and if nothing ready is available do You know what is the procedure of using it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Kernel Newbies](https://kernelnewbies.org/MailingList) mailing list may be a good resource for you.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I did. If I find the answer I will report it back here.